# Using ROLLBACK Transaction Control to undo changes made to the data in PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, postgresql, relational-database

I am making use of the UPDATE query to fetch a certain row in my PostgreSQL database by its ID and add on 2 mins to its current time. I want to be able to make this temporary change , echo out the information to the user and then ROLLBACK the changes. Will I need to use a certain function in PostgreSQL to ROLLBACK the changes before it closes the connection in the database:

```
  $countv = "00:02";
  $query =  " UPDATE test SET count = count+ '$countv' WHERE count_id= '1'";
  $query =  "ROLLBACK";

 $result = pg_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . pg_last_error());

// Printing results in HTML
 echo "<table>\n";
 echo "These are the temporary class times ";
while ($line = pg_fetch_array($result, null, PGSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "\t<tr>\n";
foreach ($line as $col_value) {
    echo "\t\t<td>$col_value</td>\n";
 }
echo "\t</tr>\n";
}
 echo "</table>\n";


 // Free resultset
pg_free_result($result);


 // Closing connection
 pg_close($dbconn);
```

Comment: Your assignments to `$query` overwrite each other, so you only execute `ROLLBACK`. The typical order for transactions is `BEGIN` ...execute SQL commands... `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`. Also get informed about [isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-set-transaction.html). There is no special function for rolling back, just issue the SQL command in a query.

Comment: Could you provide an example. I seem to be getting errors whilst I am doing this in PGAdmin :

BEGIN;
UPDATE test SET count = '14:00' WHERE count_id ='1' 
ROLLBACK; @syck

Comment: 1. the UPDATE statement is not correctly terminated, it is missing a `;` after the condition. 2. whats the point of rolling back a transaction immediately after executing an UPDATE?

Comment: The UPDATE statement will be used to alter the time column by adding extra minutes and printing out these temporary results to the user. This will only be a temporary change and not permanent which is why the ROLLBACK transaction will be used. Question is when should I call this transaction @syck

Comment: Why then not simply use time arithmetics in the SELECT statement? Like `SELECT count+ '$countv' FROM...`

Comment: That's worked. I also could do + interval '2 minutes' @syck

Comment: Yep, I should also think so. Gives it better readability.